# How to make delete button to delete recyclerview items in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I made `selectDelete` button on the main activity instead of `RecyclerView`.
When I click that button, I want to delete the items which are checked.
There is an error that checks the `RecyclerView` item checkbox and unchecks the item when scrolling.

---

Activity

```
class CartViewActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private val tag = this::class.java.simpleName

    lateinit var adapter: CartItemRecyclerAdapter

    var itemList: MutableList<CartItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_view)

        selectDelete.setOnClickListener {

            if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                  *adapter.removeItems()*
            }
        }

        swipeRefreshLo.setOnRefreshListener(this)

        itemList.add(CartItemDataVo("item1", 1, 16800, "cart_doll", false))
        itemList.add(CartItemDataVo("item2", 1, 16800, "cart_cup", false))
        itemList.add(CartItemDataVo("item3", 1, 30000, "cart_perfume", false))
        itemList.add(CartItemDataVo("item4", 1, 16800, "cart_fan", false))

        adapter = CartItemRecyclerAdapter(this, this, itemList)
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter
        recycler_view.layoutManager =
            androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
    }

    override fun onRefresh() {
        swipeRefreshLo.isRefreshing = false
    }
}
```

---

Adapter:

```
class CartItemDataVo(
    title: String,
    itemNumber: Int,
    pointValue: Int,
    imageView: String,
    CheckBox: Boolean
) {
    var title: String = title
    var itemNumber: Int = itemNumber
    var pointValue: Int = pointValue
    var image: String = imageView
    var isChecked: Boolean = CheckBox
}

class CartItemRecyclerAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    private var activity: Activity,
    private var dataList: MutableList<CartItemDataVo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemRecyclerAdapter.Holder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_list, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        holder?.bind(dataList[position], context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size


    *@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun removeItems() {
        dataList.removeIf { it.isChecked }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
     }*

    fun toggleItems() {
        for (item: CartItemDataVo in dataList) {
            var state = item.isChecked
            item.isChecked = state.not()
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class Holder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {

        var titleText = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.titleText) as TextView
        var temNumerTextt = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemNumer) as TextView
        var pointValueText = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.pointValueText) as TextView
        var imageView = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.imageView) as ImageView
        var checkBox = itemView?.findViewById(R.id.checkBox) as CheckBox

        fun bind(data: CartItemDataVo, context: Context) {
            if (data.image != "") {
                val resourceId =
                    context.resources.getIdentifier(data.image, "drawable", context.packageName)
                imageView?.setImageResource(resourceId)
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            }
            titleText?.text = data.title
            temNumerTextt?.text = data.itemNumber.toString()
            pointValueText?.text = data.pointValue.toString() + "P"

            if (data.isChecked) {
                checkBox.buttonDrawable =
                    checkBox.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_active_cs)
                val layout = activity?.findViewById(R.id.layoutOrder) as LinearLayout
                layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                checkBox.buttonDrawable = checkBox.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_no)
                val layout = activity?.findViewById(R.id.layoutOrder) as LinearLayout
                layout.visibility = View.GONE
            }


            checkBox?.setOnClickListener {
                if (checkBox.isChecked == data.isChecked) {
                    checkBox.buttonDrawable = it.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_active_cs)
                    val layout = activity?.findViewById(R.id.layoutOrder) as LinearLayout
                    layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    checkBox.buttonDrawable = it.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_no)
                    val layout = activity?.findViewById(R.id.layoutOrder) as LinearLayout
                    layout.visibility = View.GONE
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to set the checkbox listener then set data.isChecked on your model.

Comment: Thank u for answer. but I can not understand what do u mean. so can u explain more detail use example?

Comment: Can you specify what is `R.id.layoutOrder`? Your code hides or shows always same view `(R.id.layoutOrder)` I think you should change visibility of itemView

Comment: R.id.layoutOrder is not important of this problem. it is just show when item checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, replace

`var itemList: MutableList<CartItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()`

with

`val itemList: MutableList<CartItemDataVo> = arrayListOf()`

You don't want mutable property, which is also mutable collection at the same time. This is very bad practice.

Same situation in adapter

`private var dataList : MutableList<CartItemDataVo>`

replace with

`private val dataList : MutableList<CartItemDataVo>`

---

Then remove `private var activity : Activity` from your adapter's constructor. Don't put any references to `Activity` or `Fragment` in adapter!

Adapter should be only responsible for displaying list.

If in any case, you need communication between `Activity` or `Fragment` and adapter, use interface instead. This is not `ViewHolder` responsibility to hold reference to parent layout and manipulate it!

`val layout = activity?.findViewById(R.id.layoutOrder) as LinearLayout`

All lines like below should be removed from `ViewHolder`. If you need set something which belongs to `Activity`, based on action on list, use interface.

---

Finally, in adapter add method which will remove checked items from it:

```
fun removeItems() {
    itemList.removeIf { it.isChecked }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Add the following line right after `checkBox?.setOnClickListener {` (as first line in listener)

```
data.isChecked = !data.isChecked
```

And replace

```
selectDelete.setOnClickListener {

    if(checkBox.isChecked){


    }
}
```

with

```
selectDelete.setOnClickListener {

    if(checkBox.isChecked){
        adapter?.removeItems()
    }
}
```

---

Bonus:

- read about `data class`, and use it for CartItemDataVo (don't use `CheckBox` in constructor),
- `updateData` method can be optimized using `DiffUtil` for `RecyclerView`,
- it can be improved by modifying data in `Activity`, not in adapter, so responsible would be moved to better place,
- read about SOLID principles,
- read about MVVM and MVP design patterns.

Comment: Thank u r detail solution, I just apply this solution to my project. but when I clicked selectDelete, it works remove all items . I want delete that checkbox checked item. How can i do sir? and then when I use removeif , why it needs to API update??

Comment: @DaesikPark I have updated solution, making it a little bit easier, but removing elements is now adapter responsibility (added this information to bonus)

Comment: In removeItems function ,itemList replace with dataList right?, but it is not work..

Comment: @DaesikPark did you solve problem on your own or you still need help?

Comment: oh , I need help. Thank u.

Comment: @DaesikPark Can you share your current code, after my advices? It would be easier for me to help you. Use gist at github or add this code in your question (don't delete old content, just add new code below).

Comment: I just update current code, you can see * shape wrapping code, it is just different with last code. thank u .

Comment: @DaesikPark You're missing `data.isChecked = !data.isChecked`, check my answer. Also, it's better to use `onCheckedChanged` listener for `CheckBox` or `RadioButton`